# Calculate cumulative percentage for each unit over a time series

Tags: r, time, cumulative-sum

I have the following data:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
year  <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
population.served  <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500)
population  <- c(1000, 1200, 1000, 1200, 1000, 1200)
all <- data.frame(ID, year, population.served, population)
```

I want to calculate the % of the population served for each ID by year. I've attempted this, but I only manage to calculate the % served for each year. I need some way for iterating through each ID and year, to capture the cumulative sum as the numerator.

I want the data to look like this:

```
ID <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
year  <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
population.served  <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 400, 500)
population  <- c(1000, 1200, 1000, 1200, 1000, 1200)
cumulative.served <- c(10, 16.7, 40, 50, 80, 91.7)
all <- data.frame(ID, year, population.served, population, cumulative.served)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can easily be done with the `dplyr` package:

```
all %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(cumulative.served = round(cumsum(population.served)/population*100,1))
```

the output is then:

```
     ID  year population.served population cumulative.served
  <dbl> <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>
1     1     1               100       1000              10.0
2     2     1               200       1200              16.7
3     1     2               300       1000              40.0
4     2     2               400       1200              50.0
5     1     3               400       1000              80.0
6     2     3               500       1200              91.7
```

Or in a similar way with the fast `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(all)[order(year), cumulative.served := round(cumsum(population.served)/population*100,1), by = ID]
```

After some trial and error, I also figured out a base R approach:

```
all <- all[order(all$ID, all$year),]
all$cumulative.served <- round(100*with(all, ave(population.served, ID, FUN = cumsum))/all$population, 1)
```

Comment: Any `base` R approach?

Comment: My approach based on `data.table` appears to have collided with yours. I have deleted mine. Apologies!

Comment: What does the ,1 do on the final line of the dplyr code?

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge it specifies the number of decimals for the `round` function